# How to make opacity gradually scale

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div, `imgCover` that overlaps an image. `imgCover` has a background set at `rgba(255,255,255,.7)`, but I am wanting the opacity to gradually go from 0.0 - 1.0.

Is there anyway that I can get the `imgCover`'s opacity to be at 0.0 at the far left and then at the far right 1.0?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a2tayLk/2/)

```css
#conveyorSec {
 padding: 50px 0;
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
}
#conveyorInner {
 margin: 0 5%;
 width: 90%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
#conveyorInner img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#imgCover {
 width: 40%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.7);
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<section id="conveyorSec">
   <div id="conveyorInner">
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/plant-growing-picture-id510222832?k=6&m=510222832&s=612x612&w=0&h=Pzjkj2hf9IZiLAiXcgVE1FbCNFVmKzhdcT98dcHSdSk=" alt="image">
    <div id="imgCover"></div>
   </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a [background gradient](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/). [Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8a2tayLk/6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [linear gradient](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp) instead of `background-color`:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
```

```css
#conveyorSec {
 padding: 50px 0;
 height: auto;
 width: 100%;
}
#conveyorInner {
 margin: 0 5%;
 width: 90%;
 height: 100%;
 position: relative;
}
#conveyorInner img {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
#imgCover {
 width: 40%;
 height: 100%;
 position: absolute;
 background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 z-index: 99;
}
```

```html
<section id="conveyorSec">
  <div id="conveyorInner">
    <img src="https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/plant-growing-picture-id510222832?k=6&m=510222832&s=612x612&w=0&h=Pzjkj2hf9IZiLAiXcgVE1FbCNFVmKzhdcT98dcHSdSk=" alt="image">
    <div id="imgCover"></div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the help!